# Angular unit testing directive

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine

I am trying to unit test my directive that looks like this

**show-password.directive.ts**

```
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any */
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';
import { Directive, ElementRef, Inject, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[securityPassword]'
})
export class ShowPasswordDirective implements OnInit {
    private _shown = false;
    private showIcon =
        // eslint-disable-next-line max-len
        '<img alt="" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB3aWR0aD0iMTUiIGhlaWdodD0iMTUiIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAxNSAxNSIgZmlsbD0ibm9uZSIgeG1sbnM9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzIwMDAvc3ZnIj4NCjxwYXRoIGQ9Ik03LjQ5OTA4IDMuNTYzMkM1LjE0NzU2IDMuNTIzNTQgMi43MTU1NCA1LjE2Njg2IDEuMTg2NTYgNi44NDk4NEMxLjAyNjA3IDcuMDI4MDIgMC45MzcyNTYgNy4yNTkzMiAwLjkzNzI1NiA3LjQ5OTEyQzAuOTM3MjU2IDcuNzM4OTIgMS4wMjYwNyA3Ljk3MDIyIDEuMTg2NTYgOC4xNDg0QzIuNjgyMjkgOS43OTU4IDUuMTA3MzEgMTEuNDc3IDcuNDk5MDggMTEuNDM2OEM5Ljg5MDg1IDExLjQ3NyAxMi4zMTY1IDkuNzk1OCAxMy44MTM0IDguMTQ4NEMxMy45NzM4IDcuOTcwMjIgMTQuMDYyNyA3LjczODkyIDE0LjA2MjcgNy40OTkxMkMxNC4wNjI3IDcuMjU5MzIgMTMuOTczOCA3LjAyODAyIDEzLjgxMzQgNi44NDk4NEMxMi4yODI2IDUuMTY2ODYgOS44NTA2IDMuNTIzNTQgNy40OTkwOCAzLjU2MzJaIiBzdHJva2U9IiMxRDFGMkEiIHN0cm9rZS13aWR0aD0iMS4yIiBzdHJva2UtbGluZWNhcD0icm91bmQiIHN0cm9rZS1saW5lam9pbj0icm91bmQiLz4NCjxwYXRoIGQ9Ik05LjY4NjcxIDcuNTAwNjhDOS42ODY2IDcuOTMzMzIgOS41NTgyIDguMzU2MjEgOS4zMTc3NSA4LjcxNTg4QzkuMDc3MzEgOS4wNzU1NSA4LjczNTYxIDkuMzU1ODUgOC4zMzU4NyA5LjUyMTMzQzcuOTM2MTMgOS42ODY4MiA3LjQ5NjMgOS43MzAwNiA3LjA3MTk4IDkuNjQ1NThDNi42NDc2NyA5LjU2MTExIDYuMjU3OTMgOS4zNTI3MSA1Ljk1MjA1IDkuMDQ2NzVDNS42NDYxNyA4Ljc0MDc5IDUuNDM3ODggOC4zNTA5OSA1LjM1MzUyIDcuOTI2NjZDNS4yNjkxNSA3LjUwMjMyIDUuMzEyNTEgNy4wNjI1IDUuNDc4MSA2LjY2MjhDNS42NDM2OSA2LjI2MzExIDUuOTI0MDggNS45MjE0OSA2LjI4MzgyIDUuNjgxMTRDNi42NDM1NSA1LjQ0MDc5IDcuMDY2NDggNS4zMTI1IDcuNDk5MTIgNS4zMTI1QzcuNzg2NDcgNS4zMTI0MiA4LjA3MTAyIDUuMzY4OTcgOC4zMzY1IDUuNDc4OTJDOC42MDE5OCA1LjU4ODg3IDguODQzMiA1Ljc1MDA1IDkuMDQ2MzYgNS45NTMyN0M5LjI0OTUyIDYuMTU2NDggOS40MTA2NCA2LjM5Nzc0IDkuNTIwNTEgNi42NjMyNUM5LjYzMDM5IDYuOTI4NzYgOS42ODY4NyA3LjIxMzMzIDkuNjg2NzEgNy41MDA2OFoiIHN0cm9rZT0iIzFEMUYyQSIgc3Ryb2tlLXdpZHRoPSIxLjIiIHN0cm9rZS1saW5lY2FwPSJyb3VuZCIgc3Ryb2tlLWxpbmVqb2luPSJyb3VuZCIvPg0KPC9zdmc+DQo=" />';
    private hideIcon = this.showIcon;
    private toWrap: any;
    private span: any;

    constructor(
        private el: ElementRef,
        @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document
    ) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.toWrap = this.el.nativeElement;
        this.span = this.document.createElement('span');
        this.span.id = 't-toggle-type';
        this.span.innerHTML = this.showIcon;
        this.span.addEventListener('click', () => {
            this.toggle(this.span);
        });
        this.toWrap.parentNode.appendChild(this.span);
    }

    toggle(span: HTMLElement): void {
        this._shown = !this._shown;
        if (this._shown) {
            this.el.nativeElement.setAttribute('type', 'text');
            span.innerHTML = this.hideIcon;
        } else {
            this.el.nativeElement.setAttribute('type', 'password');
            span.innerHTML = this.showIcon;
        }
    }
}
```

Then my
**show-password.directive.spec.ts**

```
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';
import {
    Component,
    CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA,
    DebugElement,
    ElementRef,
    NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA,
    Renderer2
} from '@angular/core';
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ShowPasswordDirective } from './show-password.directive';
import { MockElementRef, testingModule } from './utils/mocks';

@Component({
    template: `<input securityShowPassword type="password" id="t-password" />`
})
class TestSecurityShowPasswordDirectiveComponent {}

describe('TestSecurityShowPasswordDirectiveComponent ', () => {
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestSecurityShowPasswordDirectiveComponent>;
    let component: TestSecurityShowPasswordDirectiveComponent;
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars-experimental
    let de: DebugElement;

    beforeEach(() => {
        const imports = testingModule.imports();
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [imports],
            declarations: [
                TestSecurityShowPasswordDirectiveComponent,
                ShowPasswordDirective
            ],
            providers: [
                { provide: DOCUMENT, useValue: document },
                Renderer2,
                {
                    provide: ElementRef,
                    useClass: MockElementRef
                }
            ],
            schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
        }).compileComponents();
    });

    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(
            TestSecurityShowPasswordDirectiveComponent
        );
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        de = fixture.debugElement;
    });

    it('should create', () => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });

    it('should toggle type ', () => {
        // GIVEN
        const input = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#t-password'));
        const span = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#t-toggle-type'));
        const htmlElement: HTMLElement =
            fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('span');
        // WHEN
        span.nativeElement.click();
        // THEN
        expect(input).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

But my test got error

**TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'nativeElement')**

It look like element span is not created, but in real testing all is working perfect, any info why span is not yet created??

Comment: `this.span.id = 't-toggle-type';` it is a bad practice to have non unique id on the same page - and that can cause that

Comment: Cant your image be in `assets` directory and must be inlined in code ?

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking remove `{ provide: ElementRef, useClass: MockElementRef }` and remove `{ provide: DOCUMENT, useValue: document }`. You most likely need the actual implementations of these dependencies for the `span` to be created. Also, call `fixture.detectChanges()` after `component = fixture.componentInstance;` for `ngOnInit` to be ran.